# Anchor text falling outside of <a> tag after Ajax append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading content from a URL through Ajax and appending the content to a container. When the content is appended, the anchor text falls outside of the `<a></a>` tag.

Everything is appending correctly, and the code on the URL requested is absolutely fine with no issues.

```
// url: https://example.com/index.html

<div class="data-row__classes data-row__item">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/english.png" alt="icon">
    <span><a href="http://localhost/classes/english/" class="anchor">English</a></span>
</div>

// appended HTML after ajax request to https://example.com/index.html

<div class="data-row__classes data-row__item">
    <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/english.png" alt="icon">
    <span><a href="http://localhost/classes/english/" class="anchor"></a>English</span>
</div>
// note the malformed anchor tag 2 lines above
```

I am not sure exactly how to describe this; but I can't find any other instances of this problem online. The HTML markup is absolutely fine on the requested page; does anyone know what may be scrambling it? Specifically the link and nothing else?

**Full Ajax**

```
$('.class-table__nav__favorites').on('click', function(e) {
    var class_table_height = $('.class-table__results').outerHeight();
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $.ajax({
            url: cml_theme.ajaxurl,
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                action: 'favorites_only_off',
                paged: $('.class-table__foot__nav').data('page')
            },
            beforeSend: function(result) {
                $('.class-table__results').css('height', class_table_height);
                $('.class-table__results').empty();
                $('.class-table__results').append('<div class="class-table__loading"></div>');
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('.class-table__results').css('height', 'auto');
                $('.class-table__loading').remove();
                $('.class-table__results').append(result);
                $('.class-table__foot').show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The code which it takes from the WordPress action: 'favorites_only_off' is exactly as described above with the example url (example.com/index.html).

Comment: Are you sure that when you create the structure in the Ajax file is right?
Is the link text in this case "English" inside the a tags?

Comment: Please show us your JavaScript code where you append text into anchor.

Comment: What's the format of the data that's returned? is it wrapped as CDATA or something? Or is it pure AJAX and you're doing some transform in the JS? I know you say it's fine, but it's the most logical point of failure (what you're seeing looks like it might be the result of an unterminated or prematurely terminated tag), it would be useful for us to be able to see the data and the code you're using to manipulate it.

Comment: we need to see the code which makes ajax request and adds the content to the page. Also, if you view index.html as a page on its own in your browser (not via ajax) does it render correctly in that situation? What you've posted is merely the symptoms, not the evidence that might help point to the cause. It's like telling the doctor you feel ill but not showing up for the examination and then expecting them to cure you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have updated my OP to add the ajax. In terms of loading the page in the browser, it is displayed absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(result);` inside the "success" function (and / or look  in the Network tab in your browser's dev tools and look for the response of that ajax call, to see what's in there). Does the result look like your "broken" example above, or does it look right? Need to try and narrow down exactly where the error is happening. From your ajax code sample it doesn't seem like there would be anything in there which would make a mess of it. I notice you send some parameters to the URL - is there some server-side processing going on to send a specific response?

Comment: It looked fine; I've just found some malformed HTML outside of the snippet above that was causing the problem. Very sorry for wasting everyone's time! All resolved now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Malformed HTML in a previous `<a>` that closed the opening tag with `<a href="" ... />` instead of `<a href="" ... >`